What is the difference between PLWE (Polynomial Learning with Errors) and RLWE (Ring Learning with Errors)？
Recently, I have been studying lattice-related concepts, and I want to understand the differences between PLWE and RLWE, such as how their security compares, as well as their structure and value choices. Thank you.
